how does "deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia - Release amd64 20240109]/ jammy contrib main" refer to the usb that you are installing linux mint on?
1_WHY IS THERE A "SOURCES" LIST AND A "SOURCES.D" DIRECTORY?
so if you go in your terminal and type in
cd /etc/apt/
then type in ls
you will see the file "sources.list" and the directory "sources.list.d"
2_WHY IS THERE A SOURCES.LIST TEXT FILE AND A SOURCES.LIST.D DIRECTORY?
why is there a sources.list text file and a sources.list.d directory?
for apt to work, it needs to be able to see it's sources, where it gets files to download, there are two possible ways of doing this, file or directory.
2_1_FILE METHOD
the first method your computer can use is to keep all your apt sources all in one text file,
2_2_DIRECTORY METHOD
the second method your computer can use is to have all your apt sources each in their own text file, in a directory.
Mint made the choice to move everything to the second, while a stock debian puts everything in the first by default.
3_WHY DOES LINUX MINT USE THE DIRECTORY METHOD INSTEAD OF THE FILE METHOD?
3_1_because it's easier for normies to delete a file, then delete a line of text in a text file, if you edit a text file wrong, apt has a problem
3_2_put it another way, it's HARDER for normies to mess up deleting a file and not wrecking their own system, then deleting a line of text.
3_3_The directory method (sources.list.d) allows modular management of repositories. Each source is in its own file, making it easier for tools, scripts, or packages to add or modify repositories without interfering with others. This avoids errors and simplifies automation.
4_WHAT REASONS DOES THE SOURCES.LIST TEXT FILE CONTINUE TO EXIST?
4_1_BACKWARDS COMPATIBILITY: one reason that the sources.list text file continues to exist is for backwards compatibility as the sources.list text file has been around for so many years that guys have written 3rd party software that doens't have anything to do with apt or debian, but their software relies on the sources.list text file being there and so if the sources.list text file were to suddenly disappear it could cause problems in their program regardless if the sources.list text file is actually being used for it's original purpose or not or even if it's filled with any text at all
4_2_INDIVIDUAL CHOICE: a linux user might want to keep their apt sources in the sources.list text file and not the sources.list.d directory, if so that is their choice, and the sources.list text file continuing to exist in linux mint allows that choice to exist.
4_3_TRADITION: having a sources.list text file is tradition and traditionally, thats where Linux Administrators look first when problems with the repos arise.
4_4_THE LINUX MINT INSTALLER: the sources.list text file continues to exist because the linux mint installer uses it to tell apt to use the usb or cdrom drive you install linux mint with, as an software repository when installing linux mint.
5_HOW DOES THE LINUX MINT INSTALLER USE THE SOURCES.LIST TEXT FILE?
the linux mint installer uses the sources.list text file to tell apt where to find it's sources, to use the usb drive you are using to install linux mint, as a repository when setting up linux mint
6_WHY DOES APT NEED A SOURCES.LIST TEXT FILE TO FIND THE COMPUTERS OWN USB OR CDROM DRIVE?
apt needs something to tell it where the repository it's going to use is, and when setting up linux mint apt uses "deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia - Release amd64 20240109]/ jammy contrib main"
7_HOW DOES "deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia - Release amd64 20240109]/ jammy contrib main" IN THE SOURCES.LIST TEXT FILE REFER TO THE USB THAT YOU ARE INSTALLING LINUX MINT ON?
how does "deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia - Release amd64 20240109]/ jammy contrib main" in the sources.list text file refer to the usb that you are installing linux mint on?
8_WHAT IS "DEB CDROM"?
9_HOW IS "DEB CDROM DIFFERENT FROM APT-CDROM"?
10_WHERE DOES THE SOURCES.LIST TEXT FILE COME FROM? WHAT MAKES THE SOURCES.LIST TEXT FILE?

Please remove the unnecessary text from your question. As it stands right now, it reads lika a questionnaire that has been mostly filled out.

Looks like part of an exam ...
